# List all the Claim types stored in the System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, system.security

Working with Asp.Net Identity allow you to add the claims to a user. And the **System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes** allows you to select any ClaimType from various ClaimTypes.

**ClaimTypes** is a static class and defines constants for well-known claim types that can be assigned to subjects.

I want to store all these claims in a **List<>** and display them in a **ListBox** so that the user with the **Admin** role can assign a ClaimType to a user after registration.

Seems that I can do that as **ClaimTypes** is a static class and those constants defined in that can't be listed.

Comment: Please show what you tried with (Code)

Comment: List<ClaimTypes> claims = new List<ClaimTypes>();
foreach(var item in claims)
{Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list out the claim types by reflecting on the fields in the class:

```
var claimTypes = typeof(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes).GetFields().ToList();
```

For each `claimType` in the list, you can use `claimType.Name` to get the constant name and `claimType.GetValue(null)` to get the constant value.